# Send an Email in Hindi or Other Language

Tags: send-email, language

When I try to send an email with hindi words via Send Email button in email related list in Case, its allowing me to copy hindi the content and paste it in email body and subject [![enter image description here][1]][1]

but when send and receive it in gmail or any other email service. It only show the content like this "???????????????????????????????????????".

[image]

Anybody can help me out of this. How can I send an email with vernacular language.

Comment: I think this may help you: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005102&type=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're email encoding settings are set to ISO-8859-1. This only supports latin languages (like English). If you change this to UTF-8 than you should have full support for Hindi and any other language.

This article explains it very well: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005102&type=1

If you'd like to change the setting these are the instructions from the article. You need to change this at both the user records, and at the email template records for it to have full effect.

> Navigate to Salesforce User Record
>   **Salesforce Classic UI**: Name | My Settings | Personal | Language & Timezone | Email Encoding
>   **Lightning Experience UI**: Click the User avatar in the upper right corner | Settings | My Personal Information | Advanced User Details | Click Edit - Select the required value for the 'Email Encoding' field
>
> Navigate to Email Templates
>    **Salesforce Classic UI:**
>    Name | Setup |> Adminstration | Communicaton Templates | Email Templates (select the template) | Encoding
>   **Lightning Experience UI:**
>   Setup | Administration
>   | Email | Email Templates | Select the template - Click Edit | Select
>   the required value for the 'Encoding' field

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I was wrong,This worked for me,

[image]

[image]

Symbols and special characters show up in emails sent via Salesforce
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175689&type=1